# Firebase functions issue when using res

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I get a strange error at the `async (req, res) => {` part of the code. The error message is

> "Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response) =>
> Promise<Response>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(req:
> Request, resp: Response) => void | Promise'. Type
> 'Promise<Response>' is not assignable to type 'void |
> Promise'. Type 'Promise<Response>' is not assignable to
> type 'Promise'. Type 'Response' is not assignable to type
> 'void'.ts(2345)"

I have noticed that the issue comes up specifically when I use `res` with the dot operator. I used to deploy code like this to Firebase Functions without problems. I setup the development environment from scratch and am using eslint instead of tslint. Are there changes in typescript or any of the lints that is prohibiting to compile and deploy the code? Maybe a setting in my eslint?

The only thing I suspect is that I need to define the return type of the function. But cannot find anyway to define the return type.

```
exports.fetchQuestionSet2 = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const a = 0;
  console.log(a);
  const test = req;
  console.log(test);
  console.log(res);
  if (req.method === "PUT") {
    return res.status(403).send();
  } else {
    return res.send({});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was using the `return` statement before anytime I was using `res`. By removing the `return` keywords the issue is now gone.

```
exports.fetchQuestionSet2 = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const a = 0;
  console.log(a);
  const test = req;
  console.log(test);
  console.log(res);
  if (req.method === "PUT") {
    res.status(403).send();
  } else {
    res.send({});
  }
});
```

Comment: While removing `return` works in this case, placing `return` on its own line so that it is not returning a value would achieve the same result.

Comment: @samthecodingman Not sure to understand your comment. Do you mean doing `res.send({}); return;`? Can you pls elaborate?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec rewriting  `if (req.method === "PUT") { return res.status(403).send(); }` as  `if (req.method === "PUT") { res.status(403).send(); return; }`. In this particular use case, adding `return;` is pointless, but for any future readers with this problem, it may lead to code that continues executing where it shouldn't.